# What known paradoxes are associated with having a type-level tuple indexed by all ordinal numbers?

Tags: lo.logic, new-foundations, paradox

By a type-level tuple $t(f)$ that captures a function $f$, it is meant a relation that is definable by a stratified formula that assigns to $t(f)$ the same type it assigns to each element of the domain of $f$ and to each element of the range of $f$, so $t(f)$ would be one type lower than $f$. We define "*projection of $t(f)$*" as an element in the range of $f$, that's why $t(f)$ is *type-level* since its of the same type as all of its *projections*.

For any function $f$ from a domain of disjoint non-empty sets (i.e. all of its elements are pairwise disjoint), there is a type-level ***relation*** $t(f)$, defined as:

$t(f) = \{ (a,b,c) | \exists x \in dom(f) [a \in x \land b \in x \land c \in f(x)] \}$

where $(a,b,c)=\langle \langle a,b \rangle, c \rangle $ where $\langle, \rangle $ is Quine-Rosser ordered pair.

Now we define $index(t(f)) = dom(f)$, its called like that because it meant to serve as the set of all indices of projections of the tuple $t(f)$.

We can retrieve each element of $index(t(f))$ from $t(f)$ as;

$i \in index(t(f)) \iff \exists a \exists c (i= \{ b | (a,b,c) \in t(f) \} )$

Now for every $i \in index(t(f))$ we define the notion of "*image** *of $i$ under $t(f)$*", denoted as $t(f)(i)^* $ as:

$t(f)(i)^* = \{c | \exists a \in i \exists b ( (a,b,c) \in t(f) ) \}$

So for every $i \in index(t(f))$ we define: $$x \text{ is the } i^{th} \text{ projection of } t(f) \iff \\ x= \{ c | \exists b (i,b,c) \in t(f) \}.$$ Now if $dom(f)$ is well ordered, then the order type of it would serve as the length of the tuple $t(f)$, since $index(t(f))=dom(f)$.

Since in $\sf NF$ the set of all ordinals is a set of non-empty pairwise disjoint sets, then:

In $\sf NF$ we can have a type-level tuple indexed by *all* ordinal numbers. And that's the longest ordered length a tuple can be! Any tuple of bigger cardinality would be of non-well ordered size.

In $\sf NFU$ this is precluded because no type-level function can survive existence of Ur-elements.

IF it is consistent with $\sf NF$ to have a set of pairwise disjoint sets that is larger than $T|V|$ in cardinality, then this would mean that there would be a tuple corrsponding for some injective function whose domain is that set, and such a tuple would be of the largest type-level ones known thus far.

> Question: Since $\sf NF$'s consistency is not known thus far, would having such long *type-level* tuples (can be indexed by ***all*** ordinal numbers) fall a prey to some known paradoxes? If so, what are those paradoxes?

Note: $T|X|=|\{\{x\} | x \in X \}|$

Comment: It is true that Randall Holmes's proof of the consistency of NF has not been fully validated yet, but I'm told by people who have studied Holmes's work that the proof is likely to be correct. It's just a very difficult proof to write down, and Holmes keeps finding ways to improve the explanation. That's a good thing in the long run, but repeated revisions make the verifier's job difficult.

Comment: @TimothyChow, this is a separate issue, even if Randall Holmes's proof is correct, i.e. that NF is consistent relative the  consistency of some fragment of ZF, then this won't affect the quest here. If a paradox is involved with those kinds of tuples, then this would mean that that fragment of ZFC in which Randall Holmes's relative consistency proof had been carried is itself inconsistent. Of course this is highly unlikely, since this would mean that ZFC above MacLane set theory is inconsistent.

Comment: I don't disagree; I'm just pointing out that if Randall Holmes's proof is correct then there is not going to be a *known* paradox.

Comment: @TimothyChow, the observation that there are type-level tuples indexed by *all* ordinal numbers is (as far as I know)  a new one!! So the idea of having a *known* paradox or at least some slight modification of that paradox, that is associated with existence of such long tuples might not be very remote!